Can a random field of Ito diffusions spend positive time in a Lebesgue measure 0 set?
Suppose I have a family of Itô diffusions governed by the following SDEs:
$$dX_t(x) = b(t,x, X_t(x))dt + \sigma(t,x,X_t(x))dW_t $$
with $X_0(x) = h(x)$. Suppose $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, $X_t(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}^k$ valued, $b$,$\sigma$ and $h$ are all globally bounded and Lipschitz continuous (so that there exists a modification/version of the mapping $(t,x) \mapsto X_t(x)$ which is continuous almost surely). Suppose further that $$\sigma(t,x,y) \sigma(t,x,y)^T \succcurlyeq \epsilon I$$ where $\epsilon > 0$.
Let $S \subseteq [0, \infty) \times \mathbb{R}^k$ be closed set with Lebesgue measure $0$. The condition on the volatility matrix $\sigma$ implies that $X_t(x)$ has a density and thus, $$\textbf{(1)} \qquad\int_0^\infty \mathbf{1}_S(t,X_t(x)) dt = 0$$ almost surely for each fixed $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ (i.e. the null set where this does not occur depends on $x$).
Are the conditions that I have assumed about $X_t(x)$ enough to state that $\textbf{(1)}$ holds for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$ almost surely? i.e. Does there exist a measurable set $A$ such that
$$\mathbb{P}\left(A \right) = 1 \\
A \subseteq \left\{\omega : \int_0^\infty \mathbf{1}_S(t,X_t(x,\omega))dt = 0 \quad \forall \; x \in \mathbb{R}^d \right\} \quad?$$
